# How to draw two fGarch lines in one graph in R?

Tags: r, plot

```
m1 = garchFit(~1+garch(1,1), data = priceData1, trace = F)
m2 = garchFit(~1+garch(1,1), data = priceData2, trace = F)

plot(m1, which = 1)
#plot(m2, which = 1) # if run this m2 garch graph will be replace m1 garch graph
lines(m2)
```

> Error in as.double(y) : 
>     cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

How to draw two fGarch lines in one graph in R?

Comment: what is "fGarch" lines ? you're probably using a `plot` function specific to the `garch` objects. You need to extract from `m2` x and y coordinates you can use in `lines`

Comment: probably you need `m2@fit` as `y`

Comment: lines(m2@fit$series$x)